# Is there a dynamic way to build my array so that I don't have to specify each key/element in it?

Tags: php, arrays, refactoring

So I have a function that pulls data from several different tables and puts it together into an array that I can output for a calendar/agenda. My main problem is that if/when new items are requested to be placed on the calendar, this method will just grow into a larger and larger monster. I have already added a bit of refactoring to get it this small, but it is just so big.

Question: Is there a better way to build my array or even an object that would make it clean/easy to expand in the future? Are there some blogs/articles that I could use to directly help me better refactor this method?

```
private function generateCalendarItems()
{
    //Let's build that calendar.
    $date = $this->start;
    $i = 0;
    $separatedList = $this->separatedList();
    $travelList = $this->travelsList();
    $trainingUsersList = $this->trainingUsersList();
    $newUserList = $this->newUserList();

    while ($date <= $this->end) {
        $currentDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        $separatedArray = $this->pushToArray($separatedList, ['destroyed_date'], $currentDate);
        $travelsArray = $this->pushToArray($travelList, ['leave_date', 'return_date'], $currentDate);
        $trainingUsersArray = $this->pushToArray($trainingUsersList, ['due_date'], $currentDate);
        $newUserArray = $this->pushToArray($newUserList, ['created_at'], $currentDate);
        $trainingUsersArray = $this->groupUsersForTraining($trainingUsersArray);

        if ((!empty($separatedArray) || !empty($travelsArray) || !empty($trainingUsersArray) || !empty($newUserArray)) || $currentDate == Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d')) {
            $this->calendarArray[$i]['date'] = $currentDate;
            $this->calendarArray[$i]['separated'] = $separatedArray;
            $this->calendarArray[$i]['travel'] = $travelsArray;
            $this->calendarArray[$i]['trainingUser'] = $trainingUsersArray;
            $this->calendarArray[$i]['newUser'] = $newUserArray;
        }
        $date->addDay();
        $i++;
    }
}
```

The full Calendar class can be found here: 
https://github.com/scci/security-employee-tracker/blob/master/app/Handlers/Calendar/Calendar.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$this->calendarArray[$i] = array('data' => $currentDate, ...., 'newUser' => $newUserArray);
```

Can't really get away from listing each of those keys/values to build the array, but at  least this saves you having to write out `$this->calendarArray` over and over.